# Edit default .htaccess in wordpress docker

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, docker, docker-compose

I have a wordpress container which gets generated by a [docker-compose](https://github.com/reactome/container/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml) file. Wordpress container contains `.htaccess` file by default. I want to  edit that such that that the edit is performed only once when container is created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For now I can think of two possible solutions for this problem:

1. We can use a static `.htaccess` file and mount that as a volume at the place where original `.htaccess` is copied, i.e, at `/var/html/www` inside container. From updates to this answer, I have verified that this `.htaccess` file will not get overwritten by default `docker-entrypoint.sh`.
2. We can use the docker-entrypoint.sh from wordpress docker at [github](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/php7.1/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh) and modify the part which creates the `.htaccess` file. This will keep the default behavior of entrypoint and `.htaccess` file will also be modified.

---

**Update**: Answer given by @Nazar is also correct. Having a closer look at default [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/php7.1/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh) in wordpress image, I found that there is a condition at [line 35](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/php7.1/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh#L35), which checks if `.htaccess` file already exists and creates a new file only if file *does not exist*. So, if I create my own file using `RUN`, it will *not* be overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to build your own image based on wordpress:with-netcat, with all required preparations:

```
FROM wordpress:with-netcat

RUN /. EDIT YOUR .htaccess file here ./

ENTRYPOINT ...
CMD ...
```

And to use this image instead of the original one.

Comment: That I cannot do, because changes made here will be overwritten by `docker-entrypoint.sh` which runs after image is created. It copies all content to `var/html/www` and thereby, will replace my file also.

Comment: your answer was helpful. On having a closer look at `docker-entrypoint.sh` I found that while copying all content to `var/html/www`, there is a conditional check before modifying `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky if you're mounting a directory on the host to `/var/www/html` (for example when using `-v /host/path:/var/www/html` or similar) -- the volume mount will clobber (overwrite) anything in your image.

If your host does not have any mounts, simply adding `COPY .htaccess /var/www/html/.htaccess` (or modifying the existing one with `RUN`) should work.

To get around the volume mount clobbering the image's htaccess file, write an entrypoint script to overwrite the file instead. Because the entrypoint runs after the mount exists, it will be sure to take effect.

Create a custom entrypoint shell script that copies your htaccess file into `/var/www/html` then fires off the default entrypoint:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# entrypoint.sh

cp /my-htaccess-file /var/www/html/.htaccess

# run the entrypoint from the ancestor image
docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

Then in your Dockerfile to copy your own htaccess file to a known location, add the entrypoint script, and (re)set the image command:

```
FROM wordpress:5.8.2-php7.4
COPY entrypoint.sh /my-entrypoint.sh
# RUN chmod +x /my-entrypoint.sh # uncomment if your source file is not executable
COPY .htaccess /my-htaccess-file
ENTRYPOINT ["/my-entrypoint.sh"]
# whenever the entrypoint is set, the command must also be set again
# this is the default CMD from the ancestor image.
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```